# NSMutableArray of NSMutableDictionary return always nil

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutablearray, nsmutabledictionary

I have a `NSMutableArray` of `NSMutableDictionary` but when i access the values of the array they are always nil. Here is the code i'm using

```
    NSMutableDictionary *tmpDictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    self.arrayOfData = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    [tmpDictionary setObject:@aaa forKey:Key1];
    [tmpDictionary setObject:@1 forKey:Key2];
    [tmpDictionary setObject:@1 forKey:Key3];
    [tmpDictionary setObject:@10.0f forKey:Key4];
    [tmpDictionary setObject:@10.0f forKey:Key5];
    [self.arrayOfData addObject:tmpDictionary];
    [tmpDictionary removeAllObjects];

    [tmpDictionary setObject:@bbb forKey:Key1];
    [tmpDictionary setObject:@1 forKey:Key2];
    [tmpDictionary setObject:@2 forKey:Key3];
    [tmpDictionary setObject:@50.0f forKey:Key4];
    [tmpDictionary setObject:@50.0f forKey:Key5];
    [self.arrayOfData addObject:tmpDictionary];
    [tmpDictionary removeAllObjects];
```

And i access the Array in this way

```
    for (int i = 0; i < self.arrayOfData.count; ++i) {
        NSLog(@"%@", [self.arrayOfData[i] objectForKey:Key3]);
    }
```

But the log always returns nil.
What's my mistake?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is only one dictionary, and it is mutable. When `[tmpDictionary removeAllObjects];` gets called, all the objects are removed, so it is empty afterwards. To fix this, create multiple mutable dictionaries, and don't empty them.

Answer (score 3):

The issue is due to reusing `tmpArray` over and over and removing all of the objects from the array. That won't work. Do it this way:

```
self.arrayOfData = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

NSMutableDictionary *tmpDictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
[tmpDictionary setObject:@aaa forKey:Key1];
[tmpDictionary setObject:@1 forKey:Key2];
[tmpDictionary setObject:@1 forKey:Key3];
[tmpDictionary setObject:@10.0f forKey:Key4];
[tmpDictionary setObject:@10.0f forKey:Key5];
[self.arrayOfData addObject:tmpDictionary];

tmpDictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
[tmpDictionary setObject:@bbb forKey:Key1];
[tmpDictionary setObject:@1 forKey:Key2];
[tmpDictionary setObject:@2 forKey:Key3];
[tmpDictionary setObject:@50.0f forKey:Key4];
[tmpDictionary setObject:@50.0f forKey:Key5];
[self.arrayOfData addObject:tmpDictionary];
```

Even better would be use modern syntax:

```
self.arrayOfData = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

NSDictionary *tmpDictionary = @{
    Key1 : @aaa",
    Key2 : @1,
    Key3 : @1,
    Key4 : @10.0f,
    Key5 : @10.0f
};
[self.arrayOfData addObject:tmpDictionary];

tmpDictionary = @{
    Key1 : @bbb",
    Key2 : @1,
    Key3 : @2,
    Key4 : @50.0f,
    Key5 : @50.0f
};
[self.arrayOfData addObject:tmpDictionary];
```

Answer (score 2):

@rmaddy is right.

Just as small addition.

You probably think that `-addObject:` method copies dictionary object to array (creates a copy of object). It doesn't
. 
It just stores reference to the `tmpDictionary` in dictionary. You basically save pointer to the memory part which has your dictionary.

What you do in your code:

1. Create a NSMutableDictionary instance
2. Fill this instance with some data
3. Add pointer to this instance to the array
4. Remove oll objects from dictionary (the one in the array will be empty at this point)
5. Create another instance of NSMutableDictionary
6. Repeat 2-4

To illustrate that - put this `NSLog` after adding dictionary first time to the array. This NSLog will print memory addresses of the tmpDictionary and array item with index 0. You'll see that it is exactly same object

```
    NSLog(@"tmpDictionary: %p, Array Item 0: %p", tmpDictionary, self.arrayOfData[0]);
```

Hope I explained it well...

Comment: Yes exactly! I thought it would copy the whole dictionary. Thank you all guys for the explanations :)